# Laravel project structure

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a system where the user creates a project and then the project has pages and routes.

I am working out the URL structure now and in Laravel is there a good way with middle ware to get the project information. Here's what I am thinking for the route structure:

```
{project}/
{project}/something
{project}/something/else
{project}/settings
```

`Route::group` with a prefix seems like the best way to include all the middleware. Is there a way I can write a middleware class to check if the `{project}` exists and then send the data to the view?

```
  Route::group([ 
    'prefix' => '{project}',
    'middleware' => [
      'auth',
      'getprojectstuffandthings'
    ], ], function () {
      // project routes
    }
  ]);
```

Comment: So do you want to create your own Middleware?

Comment: Yea in the code I added `getprojectstuffandthings` into the route group

Comment: Did you check the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware

Comment: what is {project} ? eloquent model? id? or what?